# Deploy rails application after git push

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, ssh, capistrano, su

I want to deploy my application on remote test server using capistrano gem.
Both git and rails should run on same server.

I have 2 users 'git' for git repositories and 'rails' with installed rvm. After *git push* i want to execute *hook post-receive* which runs *su rails* and then *cap deploy*.
When i tried push i got message:

```
remote: su: must be run from a terminal
```

How can i work around this message. Can i enable tty some way over git ssh connection?

I can give up from capistrano for this case but still i want rvm and rails to be used only by user rails (so *su* probably have to be used in each case).

---

edit
Now i walk around problem. Probably this is very bad solution but works ;). From bellow script's i removed original paths and echo's.

post-receive hook before walkaround

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    su rails #here script fails
    cd /path/to/rails/app/current/ && cap deploy
done
```

post-recive now

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    ssh rails@localhost '/path/to/scripts/deploy.sh'
done
```

deploy.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash

CAP_DIR="/path/to/capistrano/dir"
RUBY="1.9.3-p194"
GEMSET="gemset_name"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

rvm use $RUBY
rvm gemset use $GEMSET
cd $CAP_DIR

cap deploy
```

Comment: Show us this post-receive file that you have please.